# Which cross compiler?

Tags: linux, qt, compiler-construction

What is the difference between

1. [MinGW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW) cross compiler and
2. [GCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) Cross compiler.

Which one used in which operating system?

I need to create an [EXE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXE) file in the Linux operating system using Qt, hence which is the cross compiler to be used?

Comment: Which linux distribution/version do you have?

Answer (score 5):

MinGW is a GCC cross compiler for Windows environments. (There are multiple GCC cross compilers for various different targets.)

To compile Windows executables on your Linux box, you want a MinGW install for your distribution of Linux.

If you're running

- Debian, you want http://packages.debian.org/lenny/mingw32 (apt-get install mingw32)
- Ubuntu, you want http://packages.ubuntu.com/jaunty/mingw32 (apt-get install mingw32)
- [Red Hat Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux) or [CentOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS), you want several of the MinGW packages from http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/repoview/M.group.html (see [EPEL how-to](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL/FAQ#howtouse) then `yum install mingw32-binutils` and `mingw32-gcc-g++` at minimum)
- [Gentoo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentoo_Linux), see http://www.gentoo-wiki.info/MinGW
- [openSUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSUSE), then you can find builds at http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/CrossToolchain:/mingw/

Comment: i'm using OpenSuSE distro of Linux

Comment: it would be nice if u send me the link to get MinGW for OpenSuSE distro of Linux.

Comment: Good Answer.  I've been building my MinGW based program on Windows.  The next version I'll start cross compiling and this info will come in handy.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

MingW32 is a port of GCC with "win32 target".

There are two architecture in a cross-compiler: **host** and **target**. The **host** is the platform the compiler run on; the **target** is what the result code will run.

Assume you are using Ubuntu, you can see the package [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mingw32).

Comment: actually, you can even have a 3rd architecture, by building a cross compiler (canadian cross) that is built on a machine different from the one that it later on runs on: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compile

Answer (score 1):

MinGW is basically a port of GCC and related tools, allowing them to run natively on Windows machines.

Cross compiling is the act of using a compiler on one operating system/architecture to generate a binary/EXE/DLL/object that is compatible with another operating system/architecture. Basically, you ask the compiler to generate assembly and startup routines for something other than the host OS's default.

If you were on a Linux machine, you'd use GCC to compile it for the Linux machine... If you were on a Windows machine, you'd use MinGW, but with flags to tell it to compile for the Linux machine's specifications.

Comment: @Peter Mortensen, Thanks for editing my entry. I've been making an effort to do proper punctuation and caps ever since I got perl and Perl mixed up and was corrected by "brian d foy".

Answer (score 0):

GCC is usually used in Linux.. MinGW is just a Windows port of GCC to compile source to EXE files.